# Calculate costs with Average cost basis method

Tags: python, pandas

I have this pandas dataframe (that I ordered in ascending order by 'Ticker' and then by 'Date' and 'Type') that rapresents trades relative to stocks in 'Ticker' column:

```
            Type Ticker  Qty  Price  Amount  TotalQty
Date                                                 
2020-03-01   Buy    AAA   40    1.0    40.0        40
2020-03-04   Buy    AAA   50    1.5    75.0        90
2020-03-08  Sell    AAA   60    1.2    72.0        30
2020-03-10   Buy    AAA   20    2.0    40.0        50
2020-03-15  Sell    AAA   50    2.0   100.0         0
2020-03-18   Buy    AAA   50    1.5    75.0        50
2020-03-01   Buy    BBB   50    2.0   100.0        50
2020-03-04   Buy    BBB   50    1.5    75.0       100
2020-03-09  Sell    BBB   50    1.0    50.0        50
2020-03-15   Buy    BBB   50    3.0   150.0       100
2020-03-01   Buy    CCC   10    3.0    30.0        10
2020-03-10   Buy    CCC   10    2.0    20.0        20
2020-03-11  Sell    CCC   20    2.2    44.0         0
2020-03-12   Buy    DDD   90    2.0   180.0        90
```

In the 'TotalQty' column I put the cumulative sum of 'Qty' column (considering a negative sign for 'Qty' when the 'Type' column is equal to Sell).

Now I want to add another column for the average costs calculated with average cost basis method.

For example considering the ticker 'AAA', after the first  Buy, obviously I have an average cost of 1.0. Then after the second 'Buy' I have an average cost of (40.0 + 75.0)/90 that is the cumulative sum of 'Amount' (40.0 + 75.0) divided by 'TotalQty' (90) i.e. 1.278. Then, at the third row, I have a 'Sell' of 60 stocks so the 'TotalQty' from 90 becames 30, but the average cost dosen't change. Finally at fourth row I have a 'Buy' of 20 pieces, and the new average costs can be calculated dividing by the 'TotalQty' the sum of the current 'Amount' and **previous** average cost multiplied by the **previous** 'TotalQty' i.e. (40 + 1.278*30)/50 or 1.567.

The desired output should be:

```
            Type Ticker  Qty  Price  Amount  TotalQty  AverageCost
Date                                                              
2020-03-01   Buy    AAA   40    1.0    40.0        40        1.000
2020-03-04   Buy    AAA   50    1.5    75.0        90        1.278
2020-03-08  Sell    AAA   60    1.2    72.0        30        1.278
2020-03-10   Buy    AAA   20    2.0    40.0        50        1.567
2020-03-15  Sell    AAA   50    2.0   100.0         0        1.567
2020-03-18   Buy    AAA   50    1.5    75.0        50        1.500
2020-03-01   Buy    BBB   50    2.0   100.0        50        2.000
2020-03-04   Buy    BBB   50    1.5    75.0       100        1.750
2020-03-09  Sell    BBB   50    1.0    50.0        50        1.750
2020-03-15   Buy    BBB   50    3.0   150.0       100        2.375
2020-03-01   Buy    CCC   10    3.0    30.0        10        3.000
2020-03-10   Buy    CCC   10    2.0    20.0        20        2.500
2020-03-11  Sell    CCC   20    2.2    44.0         0        2.500
2020-03-12   Buy    DDD   90    2.0   180.0        90        2.000
```

I've tried with this code

```
df['AverageCost']=df.apply(lambda x: x.Amount if x.Type=='Buy' else np.NaN,axis=1)
df['AverageCost']=df.groupby('Ticker')['AverageCost'].cumsum().div(df['TotalQty'])
df.fillna(method='ffill',inplace=True)
```

but that clearly gives the wrong results. I wasn't able to obtain the correct results with `df.apply()` since, after a 'Sell' (that indeed dosen't change the average cost), with a new 'Buy' I need to access to the **previous** average costs to calculate the new ones.

Should I use a for loop and how?

Thank you for your support!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You could filter for `Buy` and get `'CumAmountBuy'` and `'CumQtyBuy'`. Then, you can merge it back to the original dtaframe and `ffill()`. This allows us to get the cumulative information excluding rows with `Sell`
2. Create a series `s` that calculates the total for `Buy` rows that DO NOT come directly after a `sell` within the same group. We will conditionally use this to calculate some of the rows in the `np.select` conditional calculation.
3. However there are two other conditions: a. rows that are `Buy` but DO come directly after `Sell` as well as `Sell` rows. For `Buy` rows that come after `Sell`, you can do the calculation you mentioned in the comments using `shift()~ to do so part of the calculation on the previous row.
4. If `Sell`, then that will return `NaN` but we use `.ffill()` to fill value previous rows.

---

```
df1 = (df.copy()[df['Type'] == 'Buy']
       .assign(CumAmountBuy=df.groupby('Ticker')['Amount'].cumsum())
       .assign(CumQtyBuy=df.groupby('Ticker')['Qty'].cumsum()))
df2 = pd.merge(df,df1,how='left',
                on=['Date','Type', 'Ticker', 'Qty', 'Price', 
                    'Amount', 'TotalQty']).ffill()
s = df2['CumAmountBuy'] / df2['CumQtyBuy']
df2['AverageCost'] = np.select([((df2['Type'] == 'Buy') & (df2['Type'].shift() == 'Sell')),
                         (df2['Type'] == 'Sell')],
                       [((df2['Qty'] * df2['Price'] + df2['TotalQty'].shift() * s.shift()) / df2['TotalQty']),
                        np.nan],
                       s)
df2['AverageCost'] = round(df2['AverageCost'],3).ffill()
df2 = df2.drop(['CumQtyBuy', 'CumAmountBuy'], axis=1)
df2
Out[1]: 
          Date  Type Ticker  Qty  Price  Amount  TotalQty  AverageCost
0   2020-03-01   Buy    AAA   40    1.0    40.0        40        1.000
1   2020-03-04   Buy    AAA   50    1.5    75.0        90        1.278
2   2020-03-08  Sell    AAA   60    1.2    72.0        30        1.278
3   2020-03-10   Buy    AAA   20    2.0    40.0        50        1.567
4   2020-03-15  Sell    AAA   50    2.0   100.0         0        1.567
5   2020-03-18   Buy    AAA   50    1.5    75.0        50        1.500
6   2020-03-01   Buy    BBB   50    2.0   100.0        50        2.000
7   2020-03-04   Buy    BBB   50    1.5    75.0       100        1.750
8   2020-03-09  Sell    BBB   50    1.0    50.0        50        1.750
9   2020-03-15   Buy    BBB   50    3.0   150.0       100        2.375
10  2020-03-01   Buy    CCC   10    3.0    30.0        10        3.000
11  2020-03-10   Buy    CCC   10    2.0    20.0        20        2.500
12  2020-03-11  Sell    CCC   20    2.2    44.0         0        2.500
13  2020-03-12   Buy    DDD   90    2.0   180.0        90        2.000
```

Comment: Indeed I also tried to calculate average cost in the way you proposed, but thats not what I need: if you look at the sixth row of the original dataframe there is a Buy of 50 AAA stocks @1.5, and that after the position in AAA stock was closed at fifth row. In this situation the average cost is 1.5 and not 1.438. What I need to calculate is: if 'Type' is Buy then average cost is (**previous**_average cost * **previous**_ 'TotalQty' + 'Amount')/('TotalQty'); if 'Type' is Sell average cost is the (**previous**_average cost) as a Sell doesen't change the average purchasing cost.

Comment: @musine can you show an example of the calculation for the first buy on March 10th for AAA (fourth row)?

Comment: As I mentioned in my original question, the 4th row is a Buy of 20 AAA at price 2.0, for a total amount of 40: since in my balance I already have 30 AAA purchased at an average cost of 1.278 I end up with 50 AAA at the new average cost of (20*2.0 + 30*1.278)/50 = 1.567...thank you for your help, I really appreciate it

Comment: @musine check now

Comment: That works! I was hoping in something less elaborated, but from what I see maybe it's not possible. p.s. I have a minor problem with your code in the .assign part since that raise "cannot reindex from a duplicate axis"

Comment: By the way I just found an identical question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63626254/calculate-adjusted-cost-base-using-python-pandas-portfolio-analysis-of-stocks but the answer proposed gives me the wrong results e.g. when a Buy follows a Sell in the same stock

Comment: @musine yeah these Qs are usually pretty specific. If you have the privileges, please remember to upvote if helpful.

Comment: @DavidErickson, what do you see if you add two purchase of AAA, say 49 @ 2.5$ on march 19th and B 49 @ 2.0$ on march 20th. When doing so, i get an average cost on the last row at 1.739, Where it should be 2.1681